# Heroku always installs yarn v.1.16.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yarnpkg

I am trying to update my app on Heroku to yarn v1.22.4 to avoid having security issues. I have run everything I can think of to update yarn to the latest version, but for some reason whenever I git push heroku master I always get the following error:

`error derp_app@0.1.0: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "1.22.4". Got "1.16.0"`

I have tried running yarn upgrade, brew upgrade yarn, npm install yarn, npm install yarn@1.22.4, all followed by yarn install to create an up to date yarn.lock, but it always attempts to install yarn 1.16.0. I've tried deleting the yarn.lock and package-json.lock and then pushing to heroku. I've tried adding buildpacks for ruby and npm. I honestly don't know what else to try at this point. Running yarn -v gives me 1.22.4 but Heroku will not accept that and I don't understand why.

This is my package.json if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "derp_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "description": "This README would normally document whatever steps are necessary to get the application up and running.",
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.14.4",
    "yarn": "1.22.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, this is expected behavior: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries. Is it because the node version is too old?

Comment: Yeah that was the first place I looked. Their only solution is to run yarn install again, which I've tried and still get the same error.

Before the yarn issue, I did get an error that the version of node was actually newer than what it expected, but that I managed to fix by changing the engines.node in package.json. For some reason it won't attempt any other version of yarn.

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles what happens if you remove `npm` from the engines?

Comment: Just gave that a try, same error with yarn